# How can I connect to Tor-browser with Go and Colly?

Tags: go, proxy, tor

There was a need to parse the HTML page .onion using the Go language. A framework for scraping Colly was taken for implementation, but a proxy is needed to connect to the tor. Colly has a corresponding function (`SetProxyFunc()`).

None of the selected server addresses (including the proxy of the torus itself on `127.0.0.1:9050`) allow you to connect to the desired resource (the timeout comes out, then eof comes instead of the code, then the incomprehensible error not implementation).

This is the proxy installation function

```
func SetLocalProxy(c *colly.Collector) {
    rp, err := proxy.RoundRobinProxySwitcher("http://203.28.8.37:80")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    c.SetProxyFunc(rp)
}
```

And this is a parsing function

```
func Parsing(){
    c := colly.NewCollector(colly.AllowURLRevisit())
    c.SetRequestTimeout(0)
    SetLocalProxy(c)
    var leakDB string = "someURL"
    c.OnHTML("a[href]", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
        fmt.Println(e)
    })

    c.OnError(func(r *colly.Response, err error) {
        fmt.Println("Request URL:", r.Request.URL, "failed with response:", r, "\nError:", err)
    })

    err := c.Visit(leakDB)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
}
```

In the example above, the proxy server "HTTP" is specified, but this is just an example. Socks5 was used for the Tor browser, which can be seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

There is an assumption that the problem is an external setup (proxy server on a PC).